# new array property not adding to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing empty array `parentChildQuestions=[]`. I'd like to add to it to build the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "001",
        "childQuestions": [
            "002",
            "003"
        ]
    }
]
```

I have the following function but the `childQuestions` property doesn't seem to be adding. My log isn't showing it at all.

```
function addToDependentQuestions (thisQuestion) {
    if (parentChildQuestions.length===0) {
        var thisParent = parentChildQuestions.push({"id":thisQuestion.Parent_Question__c});
        thisParent.childQuestions=[thisQuestion.Id];

        console.log(thisParent.childQuestions);
    }
    else {
        var foundParentQuestion = $.grep(parentChildQuestions, function(e) { 
            return parentChildQuestions.Id == thisQuestion.Id;
        });
        foundParentQuestion.childQuestions.push(thisQuestion.Id);
    }

    console.log('parentChildQuestions' + JSON.stringify(parentChildQuestions));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var thisParent = parentChildQuestions.push({"id":thisQuestion.Parent_Question__c});
```

'array.push' does not return the newly added element. It returns the new length of the array.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: There were actually a few errors in my original code, but this was the one causing the issue described